# Merge, Average, Custom Columns, etc. with Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am still new to Python and am trying to learn the possibilities along with the limitations of what I am able to do with dataframes. I will provide a sample of the 2 dataframes that I have and what type of output I am looking to achieve.

```
    df_1 = {
        'Rank': [64, 102, 34],
        'Team': ["AR Lit Rock", "Abl Christian", "Air Force",],
        '2022': [73.8, 71.5, 67.2,],
        'L3': [71.3, 77.3, 69.0,],
        'Home': [78.2, 73.6, 70.1,]
        'Away': [71.4, 70.2, 62.2,],
    }

    df_2 = {
        'Rank': [354, 284, 83],
        'Team': ["AR Lit Rock", "Abl Christian", "Air Force",],
        '2022': [80.7, 74.0, 67.0,],
        'L3': [78.7, 72.0, 75.3,],
        'Home': [75.3, 69.1, 65.0,]
        'Away': [83.7, 77.1, 70.3,],
    }
```

and I am looking for a final result that will combine the 2 dataframes into 1 while averaging the 'Rank', combining 'Team' into 1 so it doesn't duplicate, and the custom columns to differentiate the rest with new column names.

Output:

| Rank | Team | 2022 PF | 2022 PA | L3 PF | L3 PA | Home PF | Home PA | Away PF | Away PA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 209 | AR Lit Rock | 73.8 | 80.7 | 71.3 | 78.7 | 78.2 | 75.3 | 71.4 | 83.7 |
| 193 | Abl Christian | 71.5 | 74.0 | 77.3 | 72.0 | 73.6 | 69.1 | 70.2 | 77.1 |
| 58.5 | Air Force | 67.2 | 67.0 | 69.0 | 75.3 | 70.1 | 65.0 | 62.2 | 70.3 |

I have tried a little bit with concat and using mean based off of a certain column to get the average of 'Rank', but that also ended up deleting the other columns when I outputted.

```
    final_df = pd.concat((df_1, df_2)).groupby('Team', as_index=False, sort=False)['Rank'].mean()
```

When it comes to combining the 2 and outputting different column names into a certain order, I am not even sure that is possible just looking for some insight.

**UPDATE**
After testing the logic recommended by Michael, the logic is working great but then messes up when added to my master script. I am attaching an image in a link to how my script is calculating the mean of Rank and what it is outputting.

[image: Master Script Output]

I print Rank PF and Rank PA which has all the correct data, but when it finds the average is when I get a very strange number in the new Rank column.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
I have converted the Rank columns to float values before calculating and that seems to have resolved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Merge the two dataframes based on Team and use the suffix argument to create two columns for each non-Team column. Then use the two rank columns to calculate the average rank column. Afterwards, just some cosmetic work.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Rank': [64, 102, 34],
        'Team': ["AR Lit Rock", "Abl Christian", "Air Force",],
        '2022': [73.8, 71.5, 67.2,],
        'L3': [71.3, 77.3, 69.0,],
        'Home': [78.2, 73.6, 70.1,],
        'Away': [71.4, 70.2, 62.2,],
    })

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Rank': [354, 284, 83],
        'Team': ["AR Lit Rock", "Abl Christian", "Air Force",],
        '2022': [80.7, 74.0, 67.0,],
        'L3': [78.7, 72.0, 75.3,],
        'Home': [75.3, 69.1, 65.0,],
        'Away': [83.7, 77.1, 70.3,],
    })

# Merge dataframes with two columns per team
merged_df = df_1.merge(df_2, on = 'Team', suffixes = (' PF', ' PA'))

# Calculate averaged Rank
merged_df['Rank'] = merged_df[['Rank PF', 'Rank PA']].mean(axis = 1)

# Cosmetic stuff to match answer output
merged_df.drop(columns = ['Rank PF', 'Rank PA'], inplace = True)
merged_df.set_index('Rank', drop = True, inplace = True)

merged_df = merged_df[['Team', '2022 PF', '2022 PA', 'L3 PF', 
                       'L3 PA', 'Home PF', 'Home PA', 'Away PF', 'Away PA']]
```

Comment: Good answer! Setting rank as index seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I did it to match the question's output and get it automatically sorted. The first two lines of the cosmetic portion could've just as easily been accomplished with the third line and then a `sort_values()` to sort by rank.

Comment: So when I put your logic into its on script it works flawlessly, but when I incorporate it into my master script is when the Rank average gets all screwy but everything else works out fine. The data I pull is being web scraped, having some extra columns removed, and then sorted alphabetically by Team. Then when I run everything, my mean on Rank outputs numbers in the ten thousands range even when I print Rank PF and Rank PA to verify the those numbers are correct. Thoughts? I can try and add to original question.

Comment: I have updated my original question and attached the output sample to show the weird calculation occurring for my Rank column.